# CoreData - Problem accessing database on another machine

Tags: macos, core-data, cluster-computing

I've got a problem with my CoreData, but I'm sure I'm doing something wrong conceptually.

I'm trying to access a CoreData sql file on one machine in my network from another machine.  I'm trying to do this from a cluster-like application.  Each machine has the same copy of the software and needs to point to the database on this one machine.

My model and context load fine for the machine that the database is on.  The other machine, gives me error `13400 NSPersistentStoreInvalidTypeError`

Here's the bit of code:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSURL *mdlurl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"OsiriXDB_DataModel" ofType:@"mom"]];
_model = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: url];

NSURL *dburl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:_DBPath.c_str()]];
// The dburl has a format like: file://192.168.0.2/Users/slate/Documents/OsiriX%20Data/Database.sql which addresses the machine the data sits on.
_storeCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel: _model];
_context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
[_context setPersistentStoreCoordinator: _storeCoordinator];

if (![_storeCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:dburl options:nil error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error loading store: %@", error);  // Error Shows up Here
    NSLog(@"MOM: %@",_model); // Model looks OK.  Lots of print outs, with the correct names and stuff.  (so technical).
}
```

I confess to not knowing a ton about CoreData.  Is it because it's on a different machine?  I read [this online](http://www.matthew-long.com/2007/11/02/the-managed-object-model-version-used-to-open-the-persistent-store-is-incompatible-with-the-one-that-was-used-to-create-the-persistent-store/) but I don't *think* that's my issue.  If it is, I have no idea how to fix it because I can't find any `.xml` files in my `~/Library/Application\ Support/` directory relating to either `MyApp` or `OsiriX` which is the program that created the database.

Am I doing the wrong thing to load CoreData across a network?
If not, what should I be doing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that persistent store coordinator thinks that the file is not the proper format for a NSSQLiteStoreType. That suggest that the file was found. If it couldn't locate the file or access the directory you would get another error.

I'm not sure what you problem is specifically but I can tell you in general that Core Data is not intended as a concurrent database. It's not even really a database at all. It's actually a runtime object graph management system intended to manage an app's model layer with persistence tacked on the side as an option. There are no Core Data options for controlling multiple instances of an app simultaneously accessing the same store.  You might be able to do so by setting the store as readonly but I don't know for sure.

It sounds like you need a real database running on your server.

Comment: Oh.  That... sucks.  The database is a "database.sql" file.  I should be able to access that like any other sql database, yeah?

Comment: That doesn't sound like a Core Data generated file. Core Data SQL stores have the extension `.sqlite` and by default the name of the app that created the store. Core Data won't open any generic SQL file but only a SQLite file created with the (undocumented) Core Data schema. In practice, this means you can only use stores generated by Core Data in the first place. The usually solution it to write a little conversion app to translate the SQL file into a Core Data store by simply reading in the SQL data and creating managedObjects as needed.

Comment: thanks.  We're going to drop the "database" from the old program and go with something completely new.